# jquery: apply jquery .css rule if a child with a proper name exists

Tags: jquery, css, parent-child, children, radiobuttonlist

OK, I want to set margin for the second div on the page using

```
$('div#superid:nth-child(2)').css('margin-left', '10px');
```

Everything works find, I've reached the goal. But, I want that rule applied ONLY if this div contains at least one input radio with name superchild. 
So, the rule above should apply to:

```
<div id="superid">
   <div>some text
   </div>
   <div>
    <input type="radio"  name="superchild" value="2010">
    <input type="radio"  name="superchild" value="2010">
   </div>
</div>
```

because it has at least one input radio with `name="superchild"`
What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the filter method.
The script below selects every `div` in the `#superid-div`, which has at least one input field of type radio and name superchild. Then it adds the desired css to the selected divs.

```
$('div#superid > div').filter( function(index,elem) {
    return $(this).find('input[type=radio][name=superchild]').length > 0;
}).css('margin-left', '10px');
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qw6SG/)**

If you want do add this style ONLY to the second div, use your selector instead. But I thought my script covers the desired behaviour better.

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = $('div#superid:nth-child(2)');
if (div.find('input[name="superchild"]').length) {
    div.css('margin-left', '10px');
}
```